# Returning event listeners in javascript function

Tags: javascript

I'm wondering about what's happening when you end up doing something like this in a javascript function:

```
function() {    
 var privateMembers : {
  'methodA' : function() {
  },
  'methodB' : function() {
  }
 };

var publicMembers = {
  'methodC' : function() {
  },
  'methodD' : function() {
  }
 };

publicMembers.listen = {
    "myEvent:Listener" : publicMembers.MethodC;
};

return publicMembers;

}
```

I understand that returning just publicMembers makes the methods available, however, I'm also wondering would that also make the publicMembers.listen available as well?

Comment: Yes, the entire `publicMembers` object is returned. Did you try it?

Answer (score 0):

yes. these two codes are equivalent

```
var publicMembers = {
  'methodC' : function() {
  },
  'methodD' : function() {
  }
 };

publicMembers.listen = {
    "myEvent:Listener" : publicMembers.MethodC;
};
```

and:

```
var publicMembers = {
  'methodC' : function() {
  },
  'methodD' : function() {
  }
  'publicMembers' : {
    listen : {
      "myEvent:Listener" : publicMembers.MethodC;
    }
  }
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

publicMembers.listen is just a property of publicMembers object, there is no difference between declaring properties using object literals or dot notation. So, when you add listen property to publicMembers object, and you return the whole object, surely you will have access to publicMembers.listen as well. It's pretty easy to test btw.